# What kind of box does Sonny close in the "It's not personal, Sonny. It's strictly business." scene?

Tags: the-godfather

In the first *Godfather*'s "It's not personal, Sonny. It's strictly business." scene, Sonny tells Tom Hagen, "Alright. We'll wait," and closes a box. What was in that box?

Answer (score 2):

It's a cigar box or humidor. *You can see him tossing a cigar in it a split second before closing it.* **Source:** I watched the scene just now. Plus, it's definitely something that would be on his desk.

[image]